# Preventing the sidebar from sticking to the side of the browser when i use sticky-kit?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to prevent the sidebar from sticking to the side of the browser window when I use sticky-kit to stick the sidebar inside its parent element, how do I do that?

---

Before the sidebar is fixed inside its parent by sticky-kit:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUcRN.jpg)

Removing the default distance between the sidebar and the right side of the window after the sidebar is stuck inside its parent by sticky-kit :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdhG1.jpg)

---

HTML Structure is :

```
<main class="main-contents">
    <div class="wrapper">
         <section class="articles-section">...</section>

         <aside class="sidebar">...</aside>
    </div>
</main>
```

CSS Structure is :

```
.main-contents {
  --sidebar-width: 330px;
  --main-contents-gap : 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.main-contents .wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.main-contents .sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: var(--rounded-1);
  transition: width var(--transition-1);
  box-shadow: rgba(17, 17, 26, 0.1) 0px 4px 16px, rgba(17, 17, 26, 0.05) 0px 8px 32px;
}

.main-contents .sidebar.active {
  width: var(--sidebar-width);
}
```

Script Structure is :

```
<script>
    $(".sidebar").stick_in_parent();
</script>
```

I have used the following script code to solve this problem, and my problem is solved, but I guess that sticky-kit can solve this problem by using an option or event so that I don't have to write a scroll event on the window:

```
  <script>
    $(".sidebar").stick_in_parent();

    window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
      if ($(".sidebar").css("position") === "fixed") {
        $(".sidebar").css("right", "20px");
      } else {
        $(".sidebar").css("right", "0");
      }
    });
  </script>
```

In addition to the code that I have used to solve this problem, one problem it has is that the value of the right property is equal to a fixed value, and if one day the amount of padding in the main-contents becomes more or less than 20 pixels, we will have to change our script, which reduces this extensibility